# In Windows 10, how do you make icon text bold on the desktop. The size is fine

Tags: windows-10

I want to make the text bold beneath my desktop icons. I have Windows 10.  The size is fine.

Comment: Microsoft removed that ability in the creators update.  You can get 3rd party apps to do.  One of them in WinAero tweaker. https://winaero.com/download.php?view.1796

Comment: @essjae This should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft removed the ability to change the icon text properties in the Creator's Update of Windows 10, which is version 1703.

There are third party apps are available to make these changes.

WinAero Tweaker is free and allows you to do this and more.
https://winaero.com/download.php?view.1796

It can be used without installing.
On the first page you should see **Advanced Appearance Settings**, under that click **Icons.**
Click **Change font...** and you'll get your font choices and styles, click to choose what you want and then click **OK** to apply the changes.

[image]

Instead of downvoting, please leave a comment on how the answer can be improved.